# "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error on windows

Tags: python

6 hours ago i started searching for a solution to compile the c extentions for python 2.7 on windows 7.

I tried all possible solutions like taking an older MINGW version or trying it with the tdm-mingw version (4.4.) Also i tried to change the

> "-Wall -mno-cygwin"

from the cygwinccompiler
and created the new file distutils.cfg with the new build

but i still get "at least" this error:

> "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Is there anyone out there who can compile something like "pip install lxml" under windows?

If yes... please share your wisdom...;)
What kind of MINGW version are you running...what's your python version or how does your modified cygwinccompiler.py look like?

Comment: I cheated and started using www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @JakobBowyer me too...but how to do it the hard way?

Comment: Did this happen to you after you installed MinGW?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Microsoft's Visual C++ Compiler?

If not, you may want to download "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7" here to see if you can avoid the "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

That usually works for me on Windows with Python 2.7